# Working Directory: null Environment:?

Tags: java, android, linux, android-os-handler

I am trying to run below code,I am using [1]:https://github.com/rbochet/Fast-Forward-Reboot this link.

```
 try {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
                new String[] { "/system/bin/su", "-c", "reboot now" });
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And Error
     W/System.err﹕ java.io.IOException: Error running exec(). Command: [/system/bin/su, -c, reboot now] Working Directory: null Environment: null.

PERMISSIONS

```
android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE
android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE
android.permission.REBOOT.
```

I am using Android Studio ,Target Android 6.0 (API level 23)
Anybody please have an idea. thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you get any workaround for this?

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    /**
     * Checks if the device is rooted.
     *
     * @return <code>true</code> if the device is rooted, <code>false</code> otherwise.
     */
    public boolean isRooted() {
        // get from build info
        String buildTags = android.os.Build.TAGS;
        if (buildTags != null && buildTags.contains("test-keys")) {
            return true;
        }
        // check if /system/app/Superuser.apk is present
        try {
            File file = new File("/system/app/Superuser.apk");
            if (file.exists()) {
                return true;
            }
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            // ignore
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
        String[] commands = {
                "/system/xbin/which su",
                "/system/bin/which su",
                "which su"
        };
        for (String command : commands) {
            try {
                Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
                return true;
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        Log.d("message-startUp: ", "RootUtil");
        return false;
    }
```

if your device unrooted, still will bring up the same error

Comment: samsung s7 passed system/bin/which su, but it is obviously not rooted

Answer (score 0):

replace `"/system/bin/su"` to `"/system/xbin/su"`

Comment: it give me Same Error.